# How to gracefully exit a spring cloud function definition on exception scenario?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

I am using spring cloud function chaining in my project like below:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition = func_A|func_B|func_C|func_D
```

The above definition will pipe the result of `func_A` to `func_B`, and from `func_B` to `func_C` and so on...

Now if I have a business logic in `func_B` that requires to stop the propagation to the following functions (`fun_C` and `func_D`), how to do it? I know throwing an exception in `func_B` will stop the propagation, but is there any graceful way other than throwing exception?

Basically I need something like this in code level:

```
if(true){
   proceed to `func_C` and `func_D`
}else{
  stop and return (without throwing exception)
  (or) route to a consumer function (where I will just log a message)
}
```

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in terminology. You are using the word "chaining", hence your question about propagation and so on. . .
However. . .
There is no "chaining". There is "composition" and result of a composition is a single function (as if you wrote everything yourself in a single function).
So effectively you are asking how can you invoke a function without producing an output? That would simply not compile. So either throw an exception or you must return something.

Comment: I was thinking we can treat those functions in composition as individual functions and play with routing as I like. Thanks for the clarification:)